# how to install apache/php from apt alongside mysql 5.6 from source

Tags: mysql, php

I managed to install MySQL 5.6 on obuntu 12.10 but now I need apache/php packages but when I try to install them thorough apt they try to install mysql-common (presumably 5.5)
How to solve this?

Comment: When I tried, I dont see mysql. Can you please share the command which you use and the output?

Comment: I used exactly this workflow http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-mysql-5.6-on-ubuntu-12.10-including-memcached-plugin whith newest mysql

Comment: And how do you install apache and php?

Comment: apt-get php is no problem but php-mysql is... as it need mysql-common

Comment: Are you sure you did `sudo apt-get install php`?

Because I get this

`~$ sudo apt-get install php
[sudo] password for thefourtheye: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php
~$ `

Comment: you need apt-get install php5

Answer (score 0):

The package mysql-common doesn't include any client nor server binaries. It is rather a module containing the libraries and modules for php5-mysql to work with. It shouldn't be a problem for you to install php5 or php5-mysql with that dependency as it won't interfere with your manual installed version of mysql-5.6 (if you did it as recommended in /opt or /usr/local/...). PHP5 will connect against the DB just OK. It is like using a mysql-client binary a bit older than the actual server.

If you run into problems with that setup, you would have to build a php-mysql module with 5.6 bindings yourself.